# como saber el char mas repetido dentro de un array?

Tags: java, array

Necesito saber el `char` mas repetido dentro de un array

```
Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
String cad;
System.out.println("escribe caracteres");
cad = var.nextLine();
char[] a = cad.toCharArray();
```

no paso de ahí.

Comment: Qué versión de Java utilizas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que utilices un `Map` donde puedas ir almacenando la cantidad de veces que aparece un mismo caracter en la cadena. Debes tener en cuenta que, por ejemplo, `A != de a`, al igual que `a != á`.

```
    Map<Character, Integer> charCounts = new HashMap<>();
    int maxCount = -1;
    Character maxChar = null;
    for (char item : a) {// a es tu arreglo de char
        Integer count = charCounts.get(item);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }

        charCounts.put(item, ++count);

        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxChar = item;
        }
    }
```

Luego en la variable `maxChar` tendrás el primer caracter que más se repite en la cadena. Por ejemplo, en la cadena "coco" el primer caracter que más se repite es ña 'c'.

Notar que las variables `maxCount` y `maxChar` las utilizo para evitar tener que recorrer el mapa luego de haber contado todos los caracteres.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo